# Previews are blurry in folder view of KDE in Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, kde, icons

I am new to KDE Plasma and Kubuntu. After installing it yesterday, I have had an array of small petty issues that I have been fixing and it is turning me away from this desktop environment (even though its users seem pretty zealous about it).

One issue that I noticed is that I have blurry icon previews in folder mode of desktop. Here is an example:

[image]

Observe how the same previews in Dolphin file manager look way better versus the ones on the desktop? I was able to find forums across the internet reporting the same problem such as [this](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=151706), but there does not seem to be a solution present. I'd appreciate any help!

**EDIT:**
This is an already known [bug](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=391315).

Comment: I too am a Kubuntu zealot as you describe.  Over time you will realize that every distribution has its set of petty issues.  I have tried most of them over the years and in a business/education environment I keep coming back to KDE.  The ongoing development is great. It is well connected to ubuntu for compatability. As to the blurry icons I think that has been there for a very long time. Try going to settings > Icons > Desktop > Advanced and see if changing the icon size and animation change things for you.

Comment: I don't have a desktop option under icons. Though there is a setting I can get to by editing the panel and then clicking, "configure desktop". This shows a window with icons option to the left and there I tried adjusting the icon size. It did not help.